# Solr doesnt return answer when searching numbers

Tags: solr

I am querying using

```
http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q="design test"&fl=PackageName
```

I get 3 result:

- design test
- design test 2013
- design test for jobs

Now when I query using q="test for jobs"
  -> I get only "design test for jobs"

But when I query using q = 2013

```
http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=2013&fl=PackageName
```

I get no result.
Why doesnt it return an answer when I query with numbers?

In schema xml

```
 <field name="PackageName" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

***EDIT***
Here is text_en. 
It comes with the initial configuration (schema.xml)

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: How is text_en being tokenized/analysed?

Comment: Could you give the definition of that type you use? `text_en`

Comment: Added text_en definition to the original question

Answer (score 0):

The default `text_en` type does not remove numbers. You can check it in the Analysis tab of the admin panel: select `text_en` in the combo box and type `2013` in both the index and query fields, and see how they are analyzed.

The query should look like this: `http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=PackageName:2013`. `http://...:8983/solr/vault/select?q=2013&fl=PackageName` means, that you are searching in the default field (what is your default field?) and want to show only `PackageName` field in the results.